# Как передать в компонент Vue элементы HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Есть метод playSound:

```
playSound: function(tile) {
            if (this.mode !== 'light-only') {
                var audio = $('<audio id="player" autoplay></audio>');
                audio.append('<source src="./assets/sounds/' + tile + '.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />');
                audio.append('<source src="./assets/sounds/' + tile + '.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />');
                audio.append(' Ваш браузер не поддерживает ни audio ни javascript ');
                $('[data-action=sound]').html(audio);
            }
        },
```

Так же есть компонент Audio:

```
components: {
      Audio
  }
```

Нужно из метода передавать в компонент следующие данные:

```
<source src="../assets/sounds/2.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<source src="../assets/sounds/2.ogg" type="audio/mp3">
```

Передавать параметры в методе playSound. Вроде такого

```
<Audio v-bind:[params]/>
```

Но именно в методе. Как можно такое реализовать ?

Answer (score 0):

Vue.js имеет в своём арсенале директиву `v-html`, которая годится для динамической вставки HTML в компонент или тег.

Применяется примерно вот так:

```
<template>
  <div v-html="myDynamicHtml"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    myDynamicHtml () { return '<h1>Мой HTML</h1>' }
  }
}
</script>
```

Подробнее о ``v-html``` можно посмотреть в [документации по Vue.js](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#%D0%A1%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9-HTML)